# In Python, How can I convert a List of numeric array into a simple 1D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my codes, I created a list with `n` `np.array`s with various length.

Sample of how to create the list:

```
MyArr = [None] * n
for l in range(n):
    MyArr[l] = np.array([1, 2, 3])   # Example 1
    # MyArr[l] = np.array([-1, -10])   # Example 2
```

What I eventually want to do is make `MyArr` an 1D numeric array, like the following:

`MyArr = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2]), np.array([10]), np.array([-1, -2, -3])]`

Into:

`np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 10, -1, -2, -3])`

Because `n` is pretty large, I think using a for loop is not a good idea. What do you guys think?

Comment: It appears [`numpy.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) will do the trick.

Comment: @bicarlsen `flatten` is a method, so you can apply it on `MyArr` but on nd-array. So its not whats needed in this case.

Comment: Just exactly how large is "pretty large"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy`'s [concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function may help:

```py
np.concatenate([arr_1, arr_2, arr_3])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an issue with the `for` loop that build `MyArr`. Notice that you override the `l`th element because you set it twice in 1 iteration.

Second, to flatten the list of numpy arrays you could use [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) in the following way:

```
l = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([-1,10])]
np.hstack(l)
```